# php json decode/parsing poloniex API

Tags: php, json, api

I am trying to run a php script in terminal to get a organized reply of cryptocurrency data. the full JSON array can be viewed at https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker. The nested array isnt stacked with [] and parsing this format is becoming troublesome.

here is the code i used:

```
$fgc = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker"), true);
echo "Last Price: $".$fgc["last"]."    Ask: ".$fgc["lowestAsk"]."    Bid: ".$fgc["highestBid"];
echo PHP_EOL;
```

This is the error it gives me:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:
```

I have a feeling i need to define each coin however im not sure how to parse it.

other code i have tried:

```
$fgc = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker"), true);
$data = $fgc["BTC_BCN"];
foreach($data as $details){
echo "".$details["last"]."    ".$details["lowestAsk"];
echo "    ".$details["highestBid"];
echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

The error for this code is:

```
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset
```

Please help me understand how to parse this format. Thank you.

Comment: print_r the $fgc variable right after json_decode. See if you can find the keys.

Comment: print_r($fgc); gives me unorganized tables. ill attempt to sort from here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3104045/donnie-ashok thanks a bunch i was able to sort it all out after visualizing the array. Thanks a lot!